# Where to discuss questions of the "What does [tag] mean?" format?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know there are a lot of questions right now about "does this tag make sense," and that's not what I'm asking about - those clearly belong here. But when it comes to "What does [tag] mean?" it seems like there are two places that people can go to discuss that - the tag wiki (which may exclude the person who created the tag) and meta (which will exclude all the people who haven't figured out what "meta" means.)

Are there other options? Is meta the best place, given that there are so many un-wikied tags right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. As the site grows and we get people with better reputation we'll see that driven to the wiki. But for now, meta seems the best place.